# python - getting specific generator data from the generator

Tags: python, generator

let's start with the code

```
class MyClass:
   def __init__(self):
      self.elemplusone = None
      self.elemplustwo = None
      self.data = self.generate_data()
      
   def generate_data(self):
      for elem in range(10):
         yield elem+1, elem+2
```

I need to get the first and the second element of generator. Right now, I'm calling it outside the class after creating an object:

```
a_generator = MyClass()
c = next(a_generator.data)
elemplusone = c[0]
elemplustwo = c[1]
```

but I need them to be specified (as separate generators) in the class and I can't create two generator methods.

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by "but I need them to be specified (as separate generators) in the class and I can't create two generator methods." - can you add any example of how it should work?

Answer (score 0):

I also don't quite understand what you mean exactly. But does this help you?

```
class MyClass:
   def __init__(self):
      self.data = self.generate_data()
      self.update_elements()

   def update_elements(self):
      self.elemplusone, self.elemplustwo = [x for x in next(self.data)]

   def generate_data(self):
      for elem in range(10):
          print("Yielded")
          yield elem + 1, elem + 2

a_generator = MyClass()
```

`a_generator.elemplusone` is 1 and `a_generator.elemplustwo` is 2.

Now you could call `a_generator.update_elements()` to yield your elements again and continue in your generator. Please let me know if this helps you. Good luck!